# REST API for add address

Tags: magento2, rest-api

Firstly,

1. I added one address, then added another one in new call.

   - It removed the old one and have only one address.
2. Secondly, I added two addresses on one call

   - then added another new one in second call
   - It removed the all addresses and have the last one address only in my
     address book

   please let me know if anyone have solution.

Comment: Can you please share your code or which API call you are using.